# Ajax not fetching data but Wget getting the same

Tags: ajax, web-services, rest, wget, file-get-contents

I am quering a REST api hosted at amazon servers from my local system. I have shut out the cross domain origin restriction in Google chrome while firing the ajax.

Yet the ajax call fails.

I tried to wget the same URL and also tried file_get_contents() of PHP and received the required JSON object.

Is it possible that at the amazon servers, they have restricted all the ajax calls as in the Google Network tab i can see that the ajax call fails(status).

CODE::

```
$.ajax({
            url :"URL to ec2",
                type : 'get',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                console.log("OOHKK ::" + result);
            },
                error : function  (xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Desc: " + desc + "\nErr:" + err);
            }
        });
```

Comment: UNLESS we see your code we can not say anything

Comment: unfortunately i cant give away the REST url.

Comment: remove the URL , you do not need to show the URL , you need to show the code

Comment: The above is my ajax req. I receive no response. The network tab shows: Status = (failed) and type = Pending.

Comment: please check this URL http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/cloud-2008-Fall/ajax-ec2-tutorial.html . This might help

Comment: Thanks but this is about hw to login to the server etc. I guess this will not help

Comment: that also says that you need to authenticate your hosts in ec